# How to get the model name in view from self in django

Tags: python, django

IN my views.py , i want to get the Model name from `self`

I tried this `self.__class__.__name__`

but it gave me the class name of view not the Model

EDIT:

```
class ObjectCreate(CreateView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        m = self.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: can you give the code snippet where you are trying to do this?

Comment: where's the model? self is the current instance, the instance is of class ObjectCreate... have you tries model_instance.__class__.__name__?

Comment: This is my base class. i have multiple views which inherit this class. and models are defined there. now i want to get the model name so that based on model , i can get the template

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that, in a model view, self is not an object model instance.

You should write:

```
self.model.__name__
```

**Edited** *6 years later due [ihhcarus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245235/ihhcarus) comment*:

> For Django 1.11 you can use `self.__class__.__name__` to get the model class name.

Comment: This answer is outdated. For Django 1.11 you can use `self.__class__.__name__` to get the model class name.